# How to preview full-size when taking photo on Android with hardware.Camera

Tags: android, camera, photo, image, preview

I'm using `android.hardware.Camera` to take photos.  And this is my settings:

`Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();`

`p.setPreviewSize(320, 240);`

`mCamera.setParameters(p);`

And the resolution of my phone is just 320*240,so this is the max preview size.

This picture is what I see in the full screen preview. It's only the left-middle part of the full picture when I take the photo.

[image]

And I took a picture at the resolution of 1024*768:
`params.setPictureSize(1024, 768);`

[image]

Can you tell me how to preview the full picture that I'm going to take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the answer.
This is nothing about settings and nothing about Camera.
I just didn't set fill_parent in the layout of the SurfaceView!
Sorry for asking such a stupid question.